# Ruby regex string into key value pairs

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a String like this:

> ```
> price<=>656000<br>bathrooms<=>1<br>bedrooms<=>3<br>pets<=>1<br>surface<=>60<br>brokerfree<=>1
> model<=>opel/corsa<br>mileage<=>67000<br>vinnumber<=>unknown<br>price<=>145000<br>year<=>2010<br>condition<=>2<br>transmission<=>unknown<br>cartype<=>1
> ```

I want a Hash:

```
:model => 'opel/corsa'
```

etc etc... the string is variable so this is also valid:

```
year<=>2015<br>condition<=>1<br>price<=>2100mileage<=>22000<br>price<=>120000<br>year<=>2012<br>condition<=>2
```

or this

```
price<=>656000<br>bathrooms<=>1<br>bedrooms<=>3<br>pets<=>1<br>surface<=>60<br>brokerfree<=>1
model<=>opel/corsa<br>mileage<=>67000<br>vinnumber<=>unknown<br>price<=>145000<br>year<=>2010<br>condition<=>2<br>transmission<=>unknown<br>cartype<=>1
```

Comment: do you always know the keys that could be present in the string?

Comment: no, the keys are variable and can change at any time

Comment: I believe each of your three strings is missing one `"<br>"`, after `"brokerfree<=>1"` in #1 and #3, and after `"price<=>2100"` in #2. In future, when giving examples, it is helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `str1 = "price<=>656000<br>...<br>cartype<=>1"`) so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regex. You can use plain ruby methods.

```
array = string.split('<br>')
hash = Hash[array.map {|el| el.split('<=>') }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [.to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method of Array, see the following example.

```
string = "model<=>opel/corsa<br>mileage<=>67000<br>vinnumber<=>unknown<br>price<=>145000<br>year<=>2010<br>condition<=>2<br>transmission<=>unknown<br>cartype<=>1"

hash = string.split('<br>').map{|a| a.split('<=>')}.to_h

## OUTPUT

{"model"=>"opel/corsa", "mileage"=>"67000", "vinnumber"=>"unknown", "price"=>"145000", "year"=>"2010", "condition"=>"2", "transmission"=>"unknown", "cartype"=>"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is your string, you can construct your hash as follows:

```
Hash[*str.split(/<=>|<br>/)]
  #=> {"price"=>"145000", "bathrooms"=>"1", "bedrooms"=>"3", "pets"=>"1",
  #    "surface"=>"60", "brokerfree"=>"1", "model"=>"opel/corsa",
  #    "mileage"=>"67000", "vinnumber"=>"unknown", "year"=>"2010",
  #    "condition"=>"2", "transmission"=>"unknown", "cartype"=>"1"}
```

A second example:

```
str = "year<=>2015<br>condition<=>1<br>price<=>2100<br>mileage<=>22000"+
      "<br>price<=>120000<br>year<=>2012<br>condition<=>2"
Hash[*str.split(/<=>|<br>/)]
  #=> {"year"=>"2012", "condition"=>"2", "price"=>"120000", "mileage"=>"22000"}
```